# SSIS Package and Configuration File

Tags: deployment, configuration, ssis

I created a SSIS 2008 package with configuration file and deployment utility. I installed the package on SQL Server under MSDB. At the time of installation I choose my own installation path where I wanted to dependencies of the package to be copied (config file). All went fine,
now when I try to run the package directly from under MSDB and choose a configuration file from some other location not from the installation folder. In the progress I see the package is reading config file from the installation folder not from the folder that I specified in Configurations tab. Is that the right behavior? If so then whats the use of adding a different config file?

Comment: I suggest that you make an account in SQL server central and MSDN forums for SSIS. Not too many SSIS/ETL folks around here. I got the most help from MS, then SSC and almost none from SO. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the config file from the default design time location - then it will use a new location, if a config file exists in the default location SSIS will always use it.

Well that's my experience anyway - I've lost count how many times this behavior has caught me out.